# Start/stop sqsd daemon on Elastic Beanstalk to view SQS queue messages

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to view SQS messages before they get picked up by sqsd on my Elastic Beanstalk intstance. Is there a way, once ssh'ed into the instance, that sqsd can be stopped / started as a service all together?

Answer (score 12):

For the purpose of debugging you may stop sqsd by running `sudo service aws-sqsd stop` on the instance. You can check the status by running `sudo service aws-sqsd status`. Note this is not recommended for a production service but for the purpose of debugging you may try this.

Comment: I am getting "aws-sqs: unrecognized service". The daemon seems to be working.

Comment: It is aws-sqsd ... I had aws-sqs at one place in my answer above. Fixed it.