# Elastic Beanstalk Work Tier - stop/start message processing

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

Could I stop / start the message processing in Elastic Beanstalk Work Tier?

Comment: When do you want to start or stop it? Manually or based on some automated trigger?

Comment: In both situations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start/stop the aws-sqsd daemon running on the EC2 instances but that is not recommended in production.
Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222164/161628

If your usecase is to automatically scale to zero EC2 instances when there are no messages to process and scale back up once there are messages you may want to set up a cloudwatch alarm on SQS ApproximateNumberOfMessages metric and trigger auto-scaling to shutdown EC2 instances by scaling down to zero instances. Is that your usecase?

Comment: Think a production bug... to fix it, I need stop the service... How can I do?

Comment: Stop the beanstalk environment completely or just worker tier daemon?

Comment: If you can give more details about your usecase preferably with an example it will be useful. Why do you want to stop message processing in production?

Comment: For example... I have 10k messages in the queue to be processed, but I need to stop the environment for scheduled maintenance. How can I stop worker tier deamon in all ec2 instances of the load balancer?

Comment: One way of doing it is to go to the EC2 console, set the autoscaling group min and max size to zero. All instances in your environment will be terminated. When the maintenance is done you can set the auto scaling group min and max size to original values.

Comment: The Desired parameter must be set to 0 too. Tks for your help.