# How to prevent long running jobs on Elastic Beanstalk from being terminated without blocking scaling in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a number of parallel workers processing long running jobs on the elastic beanstalk worker environment. The underlying EC2 instances are scaled based on the length of the queue. My problem is that the workers are terminated during processing, while a scaling in action occurs.

My initial approach to prevent this looks as follows:
Every worker is protecting the EC2 instance he is running on, after he receives the message from the sqs daemon. When the worker is ready processing the job, he unprotects the EC2 instance again. This seems to be the recommended approach for this kind of situation: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/protect-instances-from-termination-by-auto-scaling/ 
And it worked, besides the fact, that it does not take into account any placement strategies. It resulted in all instances being protected and the scaling action was cancelled most of the time. The sqs daemon seems not to take into account filling the instace with as many workers as possible.

My next consideration is to stop the sqs daemon when a scaling in action is triggered, for example using an auto scaling lifecycle hook. But with this approach the termination protected instances might still be an issue (I don't know whether the hook is triggered on protected instances). Besides, it seems not to be recommended to stop the sqs daemon: [Start/stop sqsd daemon on Elastic Beanstalk to view SQS queue messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172661/start-stop-sqsd-daemon-on-elastic-beanstalk-to-view-sqs-queue-messages)

How can I fulfill both requirements (1. don't stop long running workers and 2. run as many workers per EC2 instance as possible) with the elastic beanstalk worker tier?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Beanstalk worker tier instances, but as far as I know, they get 1 task at a time, correct?  If so, why do you need to stop the SQS Daemon, presumably if a scale in is occuring, its because there are no more tasks in the worker queue, so this instance shouldn't get a new one.  If one does happen to come in right at that moment, it wouldn't get deleted from the SQS queue, and as soon as the visibility timeout ends would be picked up by another worker node.

A lifecycle hook wouldn't be triggered until after the instance protection has been disabled, since it only starts when the instance is picked to be terminated.

If you are able to add a piece of logic to your code stating that 'if a task ends and no new one comes in -> then disable instance protection on this instance'
That way only the instances with no tasks are able to be terminated.

Alternatively, you could leave everything constantly protected, and have a bash script running on the instance periodically via a Cron job checking if it's currently running a job or not, and if its not then disable instance protection

Comment: Can you please add a tag for your topic. so that people can easily identify your question from Tags.